# Any way to limit size of set return by Spring redisTemplate.keys()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I want to search keys from edis using keys operation. However the number of results around 1 million. But I just want to get max 300 keys in descending order.

```
@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

...

redisTemplate.keys("rec:*:type:3001:bill:*").stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).forEach((receivedBill) -> {

});;
```

Any way can I limit the size of result set of keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would better store the keys as a set of values to the redis. So you can get the keys as values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using scan function like this

```
public Set<String> fetchEventsFromRedis(long count, String pattern){
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>();
    Cursor<EnoEvent> cursor = redisTemplate.opsForSet().scan(EVENT_KEY, ScanOptions.scanOptions().count(count).match(pattern).build());
    if(cursor!=null){
        while(cursor.hasNext()){
            keys.add(cursor.next().getKey());
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

The function count() will limit the number of keys that you want to fetch
and match() will take care of the keys pattern that you want to search.

P.S. - check the count functionality at redis. It is NOT bound to return exactly the mentioned number of records every time.